# Why did wget changed structure of my yml file? error: error parsing .yml

Tags: github, wget

I have this file

```
---
apiVersion: metallb.io/v1beta1
kind: IPAddressPool
metadata:
  name: first-pool
  namespace: metallb-system
spec:
  addresses:
    - 192.168.2.143-192.168.2.144

---
apiVersion: metallb.io/v1beta1
kind: L2Advertisement
metadata:
  name: empty
  namespace: metallb-system
```

I checked with yamllint,confirmed yaml format.
then I go for gist wget

```
wget https://gist.github.com/jholmes/cd3c7bff15733808e8b723fe710fa1ee -O metallb-ipaddresspool.yml
```

When I try

```
kubectl apply -f metallb-ipaddresspool.yml
```

got error

```
error: error parsing metallb-ipaddresspool.yml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 107: mapping values are not allowed in this context
```

output from yammllint command line

```
yamllint metallb-ipaddresspool.yml
metallb-ipaddresspool.yml
  6:1       error    too many blank lines (6 > 0)  (empty-lines)
  8:81      error    line too long (122 > 80 characters)  (line-length)
  18:1      error    trailing spaces  (trailing-spaces)
  20:81     error    line too long (1531 > 80 characters)  (line-length)
  21:81     error    line too long (146 > 80 characters)  (line-length)
```

when I cat my file
c

```
at metallb-ipaddresspool.yml 






<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-color-mode="auto" data-light-theme="light" data-dark-theme="dark" data-a11y-animated-images="system">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://github.githubassets.com">
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com">
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com">
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://github.githubassets.com" crossorigin>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com">
```

Why?
What should be alternative,download from gist to remote server?

Comment: That sounds pretty strange. "line 107" - the file you've shared doesn't contain 107 lines

Comment: @NicoHaase yes,exactly.

Comment: Did you verify the content of your downloaded yaml file? I.e. does it look exactly the same as your original yaml?

Comment: @IgorTopolski No,it looks like an HTML file,I do not know why yaml format is not preserved.

Comment: So that's your answer :) You probably download the HTML content (which will have all the beautiful stuff you see on GitHub). You should use a raw version of the gist, in top-right of your file-content window you have a `Raw` button. If you use that link instead, it should only have raw content.

Comment: @RichardRublev Also, bear in mind it will work with public gists. If your gist is private  it will just contain GitHub's 404 page (as per this link you shared https://gist.github.com/jholmes/cd3c7bff15733808e8b723fe710fa1ee). If you try to access it through private browser window where you're not logged in to GitHub, you will see what content it will attempt to download

Comment: @IgorTopolski I will make it public,can not complicate things too much.